# ExtJS and Sencha Touch: Adding a second panel at bottom with text that depends on a function call

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have Sencha Touch application that currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7V44.png). The top navigation bar is appearing correctly as intended, but I want to have a bottom bar as well. I also want the bottom bar to display text based on values I get from stores. I am using Sencha Touch 2.3. How might I accomplish this?

Here is the view for the above page:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Mod.Home', {
        extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
        alias: 'widget.modHome',

        config: {
            navigationBar: {
                docked: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Logout',
                        ui: 'back',
                        itemId: 'logoutBtn',
                        align: 'left'
                    },
                    {
                        align: 'right',
                        itemId: 'showMapBtn',
                        text: 'Show Map',
                        ui: 'action'
                    },
                    {
                        align: 'right',
                        itemId: 'modGraphBtn',
                        text: 'Stats'
                    },
                    {
                        align: 'right',
                        hidden: true,
                        itemId: 'submitBtn',
                        text: 'Submit',
                        ui: 'action'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Role',
                        itemId: 'rolesBtnMod'
                    }
                ]
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    title: 'Home',
                    store: 'modList',
                    disableSelection: true,
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div class="x-container x-field-checkbox x-field x-label-align-left x-field-labeled" style="background: none">',
                            '<div class="x-form-label" style="background: none;padding: 0">',
                                '<div>{FirstName} {LastName}</div>',
                            '</div>',
                            '<div class="x-component-outer">',
                                '<div class="x-unsized x-field-input" style="border: 0; background: none;">',
                                    '<input type="checkbox" <tpl if=\'modStatus != null && Accepted !== false\'>checked="checked"</tpl> class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox">',
                                    '<div class="x-field-mask"></div>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</div>',
                        '</div>'
                    ],
                    plugins: [{type: 'pullrefresh'}]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'tabpanel', // <--- This is what I've tried so far, although I think that tabpanel is the wrong object to use. Panel does not work, however.
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    store: 'manageMods',
                    title: new Ext.XTemplate(
                         'tpl if="values.isActive == \'1\'">' + "{someStringValue}"
                     )
                }
            ]
        }

    });
```

Please note that this is not my original code base, and I realize that some of the elements are being used incorrectly. Refactoring the entire codebase to adhere to the latest standards in the docs would be a huge undertaking in itself, so right now I am only trying to keep the style consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there is a syntax error in your `tabpanel` declaration, missing a comma before `title`.  However what I think you want to implement is a docked toolbar at the bottom of the view like this:-

```
    Ext.define('App.view.Mod.Home', {
        extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
        alias: 'widget.modHome',

        config: {
            navigationBar: {
                docked: 'top',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Logout',
                    ui: 'back',
                    itemId: 'logoutBtn',
                    align: 'left'
                }, {
                    align: 'right',
                    itemId: 'showMapBtn',
                    text: 'Show Map',
                    ui: 'action'
                }, {
                    align: 'right',
                    itemId: 'modGraphBtn',
                    text: 'Stats'
                }, {
                    align: 'right',
                    hidden: true,
                    itemId: 'submitBtn',
                    text: 'Submit',
                    ui: 'action'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Role',
                    itemId: 'rolesBtnMod'
                }]
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'list',
                title: 'Home',
                store: 'modList',
                disableSelection: true,
                itemTpl: ['<div class="x-container x-field-checkbox x-field x-label-align-left x-field-labeled" style="background: none">', '<div class="x-form-label" style="background: none;padding: 0">', '<div>{FirstName} {LastName}</div>', '</div>', '<div class="x-component-outer">', '<div class="x-unsized x-field-input" style="border: 0; background: none;">', '<input type="checkbox" <tpl if=\'modStatus != null && Accepted !== false\'>checked="checked"</tpl> class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox">', '<div class="x-field-mask"></div>', '</div>', '</div>', '</div>'],
                plugins: [{
                    type: 'pullrefresh'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'toolbar', // <--- This is what I've tried so far, although I think that tabpanel is the wrong object to use. Panel does not work, however.
                docked: 'bottom',
                itemId:'myToolbar',
                title:'Test',
                //store: 'manageMods',
                //title: new Ext.XTemplate('tpl if="values.isActive == \'1\'">' + "{someStringValue}")
            }]
        }

    });

    var homeContainer = Ext.create('App.view.Mod.Home', {renderTo:Ext.getBody(), fullscreen:true});
    // Now you can get a reference to the toolbar and change it's title to whatever you want e.g.:-
    homeContainer.getComponent('myToolbar').setTitle('The 2nd test');
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j8h

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks great! Is it possible to use a store in that container similar to how it is used in the `list` container of the original navigation bar? The title I wish to set would rely on the some store values.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would need to attach the store to the toolbar.  You can instantiate the store separately and query it's values and then `setTitle` on the toolbar.  Since toolbar doesn't inherit anty data-bound properties a store is not accepted in anycase in the config.